# Displaying html file after PHP function

Tags: php, html

After a user has registered, I send an email verification link to the email used for verification. When the user clicks on the link, I have a php api that validates the code and updates the DB. Upto this its working fine. Once that is done successfully, I want to display a message saying email is verified and provide the link for login. I am stuck here.

My echo display as it is with the html tag. I am new to PHP and unable to proceed. Please help.

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

    include_once '../config/database.php';
    include_once '../class/users.php';
    require_once('../config/constants.php');
    
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    $item = new User($db);

    $item->hash = isset($_GET['ticket']) ? $_GET['ticket'] : die();
    
    $encryptedMessage = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : die();
    $decryptedMessage = openssl_decrypt($encryptedMessage, ENCRYPT_ALGO, SALT);

    $item->email = $decryptedMessage; 
    
    $item->verifyEmail();

    if($item->user_id != null){
        $item->updateEmailVerified($item->user_id);
        echo "<p style='color:red;'>" . "Hello Word" . "</p>"; // --- Displays as it is ---
    }
      
?>
```

[image]

Comment: You're explicitly setting the header to tell the browser to expect JSON data: `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");`  Why?

Comment: You have `Content-Type: application/json;`, so this page cannot be HTML.

Comment: Also if this is intended to be a link clicked on from an email, why have you set all those CORS-related headers (the "Access-Control" ones) at the top? They just open up a security hole for no reason, if you don't actually want the page to be accessed via a CORS request. I smell some programming-by-guesswork going on here. If you don't understand what a line of code does either a) go and do some research so you can understand its purpose, or b) don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content type is set to "application/json" here:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Try changing it to:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```